# "This" and "that"

Tags: word-choice, definite-article, determiners

Ridiculous examples, yet, what do you think?:

- This darkness is giving me the creeps.
- That air isn't any healthy.
- This weather is cold.
- That heat burns to the bone!

Is it correct to use "this" or "that" instead of "the"?

Comment: Sure.  It's no different from any other use of "this" - it indicates the specific one that's conceptually near.  *All* darkness doesn't give me the creeps, just this specific darkness that we're experiencing right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The is a determiner. Used in these sentences, [This](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/this) and [That](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/that) are also determiners.

You can use **this** interchangeably with **the**, without any obvious change of meaning. if you use **that**, without providing any additional context, the listener will wonder why.

You normally use **that** to imply that something is further away in distance (that place) or in time (that day/those days), or to refer dismissively to something ([that woman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewinsky_scandal)).